# Mac Book Pro - Logic board stopped working

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware, warranty, applecare

I Had purchased Mac Book Pro before around 14 month from one of the apple store. It just blinking and doesn't start. As per customer service they ask to replace logic board and It costs almost around $650 (38500 Rupee). And my warranty is just expired before two month. I believe that I got defective model of Mac Book Pro, As In My warranty period also there were such issues and it was issue of hard disk.

I am a normal user regarding to use Mac Book. I don't do gaming and etc.I just use it for my professional purpose.

I can't pay this much amount again in around one year duration. Please suggest what is alternative or what can I do As warranty is expired.

Thanks.

Comment: They always want to replace the entire logic board :(, so tell us more so we can try to narrow it down to what is not working. Did you try to start in Safe mode, (hold shift key during start up). Or start up while holding "cmd+r" to get in to the recovery mode.

Comment: @Buscar웃 Thanks for your feedback, It's still with customer service center, I will get back it within two days and check in safe mode if it starts. Also as per service center they told to replace so don't know if it can work by changing any in logic board. May need to check with other than service center.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked to see if it is under recall?

http://www.apple.com/support/macbookpro-videoissues/

Comment: Oops sorry, this was supposed to be a comment, not an answer, lol.  But the question remains - I just want to make sure you've checked to see if it's under recall.  Otherwise there's really not much you can do other than to try to talk to a sympathetic Genius.

Comment: I will check today surely. Need to check from receipt as Mac book is still in service center. Thanks for this link.